# Are callbacks the only way a web API binding is linked with the Javascript engine?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

In the context of the browser, is it safe to say that the only possible link between a web API binding (eg: `setTimeout()`) and the Javascript engine is via a callback function?

ie: callback function -> callback queue -> event loop -> Javascript engine

Or are there other mechanisms that could be used by some native code to communicate back with the Javascript engine?

Comment: The answer depends on how you define "web API".  The vast majority of DOM APIs, for example, are simple synchronous function calls.

Comment: Synchronous function calls returning a value, Promises returning a Deferred...

Comment: It would help people provide an answer if you could describe a programming situation in which this would provide significant guidance.

Comment: I see. I did not realize that DOM API calls could be synchronous. So the majority of DOM APIs (or for that matter any piece of synchronous code that lies outside of the engine) will still run on the main thread of the Javascript engine? I guess my question is then "are callbacks the only way an **asynchronous web API** binding is linked back to the Javascript engine?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are callbacks the only way a web API binding is linked with the JavaScript engine?

No. `document.createElement` is one of many counter-examples.

> Are callbacks the only way an asynchronous web API binding is linked back to the Javascript engine?

Yes. Callbacks are the only way *any* asynchronous API works, that's pretty much the definition of "asynchronous API". (Not just in JavaScript or on the web.)

Comment: What about promises though? I'd expect there to be native interfaces for constructing and asynchronously resolving promises, so an API binding might just return a promise and not explicitly schedule any callbacks itself.

Comment: Promises are just syntactic sugar (and an organizational help) around callbacks. Ultimately it doesn't matter who schedules the callback, whether it's an embedder-written function or a helper provided by the engine (and called, directly or indirectly, by the embedder).